# Function to create a list of months where januari is a date and other months are strings

Tags: python, list, datetime

I aim to develop a function that creates the list target_list, see below.
Target list has the following structure, it always starts with a date, '1995-01-01', then follows eleven elements representing the following eleven month of the year. After 'dec' I want a new datestring, '1996-01-01' and then comes the months as last year.

Target list below has length 27. I want the function to has the length of target_list as a parameter. If 28, one element would be added to target_list('april').

```
target_list=['1995-01-01','feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1996-01-01',
'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1997-01-01', 'feb', 'mar']
```

The code below returns the list I want. Because I want a list of 27 months I loop over 3 years. That force me to remove the last nine elements of the list. I struggle to find a way to make this process automated. Perhaps I want a list of 145 months. The function must know how many elements to remove. This I haven't figured out. Any help or recommendations would be much appreciated. Of course more efficient solutions is also of great interest.

```
import math
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

def add_years(d, years):
    try:
        return d.replace(year = d.year + years)
    except ValueError:
        return d + (date(d.year + years, 1, 1) - date(d.year, 1, 1))

year=pd.to_datetime('1994-01-01')
years=math.ceil(27/12) #For 27 month I need three years. Use math.ceil to "round" upwards.

target=[] 

for i in range(1,years+1): # Loop over the number of years
    year=add_years(year,1) # Add one year for each loop
    y=[year.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] 
    z=y+ month # Concat the lists
    
    target=target + z # Concat with target
    
target_list=target[:len(target)-9] # Remove the last nine elements of the list 

print(target_list)
```

This is one solution.

```
def get_list(no_month):
    
    import math

    year=pd.to_datetime('1994-01-01')
    years=math.ceil(no_month/12)
    remove=(years*12)-no_month
    target=[]
    
    for i in range(1,years+1): # Loop over the number of years involved
        year=add_years(year,1) # Add one year for each loop
        y=[year.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] 
        z=y+ month # Concat the lists
    
        target=target + z # Concat with target
    
    target_list=target[:len(target)-remove]
    
    return target_list
```

Comment: I could of course use take 3*12-27 to get the number of elements to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for this task as follows

```
import itertools
def months():
    year = itertools.count(1995)
    for m in itertools.cycle(['y', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec']):
        yield '{}-01-01'.format(next(year)) if m=='y' else m
target145 = list(itertools.islice(months(),145))
print(target145)
```

output

```
['1995-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1996-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1997-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1998-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '1999-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2000-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2001-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2002-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2003-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2004-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2005-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2006-01-01', 'feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec', '2007-01-01']
```

Explanation: firstly I create endless iterator months, internally I use `itertools.cycle` to cycle month codes, I used `y` letter to denote where year should appear, when it so I take `next` year starting from 1995. I use `.format` to get desired str holding year, otherwise month case is provided as-is. Then I get 145 first elements of endless `months()` and convert it into `list` to comply with requirements imposed.

Answer (score 1):

You  want to know how much months are left for a full year and can use modulo for that:

```
months = 27
toRemove = 12 - (months % 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def target_list(length=27):
    target = []
    start = datetime.strptime("1995-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
    for i in range(length // 12 + (1 if length % 12 != 0 else 0)):
        target.extend([
            start.replace(year=start.year + i).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            'feb',
            'mar',
            'april',
            'maj',
            'jun',
            'juli',
            'aug',
            'sep',
            'okt',
            'nov',
            'dec',
        ])
    return target[:length]

print(target_list())
```

This will populate the list with full 12 values and then will cut it by the given length

Answer (score 1):

```
date = "1995-01-01"
numberOfMonth = 27
month =['feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec']

date=int(date[0:4])
output = []

for i in range(numberOfMonth):
    if not i%12:
        output.append(str(date+i//12)+"-01-01")
    else:
        output.append(month[i%12-1])

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

months = ['feb', 'mar', 'april', 'maj', 'jun', 'juli', 'aug', 'sep', 'okt', 'nov', 'dec']
def add_years(d, years):
    """Return a date that's `years` years after the date (or datetime)
    object `d`. Return the same calendar date (month and day) in the
    destination year, if it exists, otherwise use the following day
    (thus changing February 29 to March 1).

    """
    try:
        return d.replace(year = d.year + years)
    except ValueError:
        return d + (date(d.year + years, 1, 1) - date(d.year, 1, 1))
    
def create_target_list(n):
    m = n//12 # floor division to get the number of times
    date_zero = '1995-01-01'
    date_zero=pd.to_datetime(date_zero)
    target_list = []
    for k in range(m):
        target_list.append(str(date_zero)[:10])
        target_list.extend(months)
        date_zero = add_years(date_zero, 1)
    if n%12 > 0 :
        if n%12 == 1:
            target_list.append(str(date_zero)[:10])
        else :
            target_list.append(str(date_zero)[:10])
            target_list.extend(months[:n%12-1]) 
    return target_list

#print(create_target_list(26))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

def genvals(start_date, length):
    d = datetime.strptime(start_date, FORMAT)
    for _ in range(length):
        yield datetime.strftime(d, FORMAT) if d.month == 1 else d.strftime('%b')
        d += relativedelta(months=1)

def genlist(start_date, length):
    return [d for d in genvals(start_date, length)]

print(genlist('1994-01-01', 27))
```

**Output:**

```
['1994-01-01', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', '1995-01-01', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', '1996-01-01', 'Feb', 'Mar']
```

**Note:**

The actual output will vary depending on your locale